# Testing scenarios with exponentially growing outcomes

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

One of the things that really draws me to TDD is the clear development of your spec alongside implementation.

I am seeking to implement a constructor that accepts a configuration object

```
function MyConstructor(conf) {}
```

`conf` is currently spec'd to have two keys: `a` and `b`, where `a` is a `RegExp` and `b` is a `Function`, and as part of my TDD spec elucidation ambitions, I am writing tests that spec out this object as such:

- I would like `MyConstructor` to throw an `Error` if either `a` is not a `RegExp` or `b` is not a `Function`.
- `MyConstructor` throws an `Error` if either `a` or `b` is missing from the configuration.

Now, I know that I could encapsulate this behavior in some other constructor, say a `Configuration` constructor that creates "configuration" objects. But the way I am seeing this now, regardless of where this behavior ends up, this behavior has to be encapsulated *somewhere* for this spec to be elaborated via TDD.

The problem is: I seems to me that as the number of keys on the `conf` object grows, so does the number of tests—exponentially! This is especially due to the second bullet above.

For example, say I have 4 keys: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, and I need to make sure that if any are missing an Error is thrown. *It seems* that this requires that I write a ton of identical, banal tests that cover all the possibilities (**combinations**!) for missing keys. That doesn't sound right! Yet, I can't think of a good way explicitly or inductively test that all scenarios are covered. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm a little confused on the problem. The spec would state that the ctor will fail if it's missing any of an arbitrary number of an arbitrary number of keys. You don't have to test all combinations (and you could do so programmatically anyway), you just have to make sure if any required key is missing it throws. Sounds like simple object validation, for which pre-built solutions exist.

Comment: @DaveNewton, so in my limited experience with unit tests, I've never seen one written with a loop or nested loops, iterating over combinations. Are you saying that's an alright thing to do in light of tests having to be (a) fast (b) simple? (not sure about that last one, but that's been my impression).

Comment: How would creating permutations programmatically be slower, in a *meaningful* way, than the same tests written out by hand? They'd also be more likely to be more-correct over time if you *actually* need to test all permutations... which I'm pretty skeptical about, if we're talking solely about the need to ensure all required parameters are present.

Comment: @DaveNewton, you're totally right, but should I be writing those loops in the first place? I _would_ _totally_ love to spec out every detail of my spec via test, but I also don't want to do thinks to JavaScript that shouldn't be done to JavaScript. What do you think?

Comment: I don't see an issue with generating test data programmatically. I even generate tests and specs programmatically, although not in JavaScript.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks again for your perspective. Perhaps you would elaborate as an answer so that I may vote up? I've taken to your approach and really like how it lets me spec things out. Still I find it difficult to reconcile with perspectives like: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test and the whole **Arrange, Act, Assert, End of test** thing. But what's a person to do?

Answer (score 1):

Objects without a class definition or interface are hard to test. If your objects are *ducks* you'll need to use *ducktyping* to check.

You can also wonder about how useful it is to completely test certain functions. You can test the boundaries but you can never test all values;

If your function looks like this:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    if (a === 42) {
        throw new Error("All glory to the hypnotoad");
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

how are you expected to find this *bug*?

Comment: So, I was thinking that but didn't mention it in the question. That being your perspective, how, then, am I supposed to elaborate a spec? JS sucks for spec'ing via TDD? The cleanest way to use the language is duck typing and not stressing about features of the language that aren't there.

Comment: JS lacks interfaces so TDD is limited.

Comment: Calm down there Morgan. You can always introduce a typing system of your own, at the expense of some overhead.

Comment: Hahaha I'm trying, I'm trying. Just a bit frustrating. Yeah, duck typing is great, but then I have to lean heavily on integration tests for runtime behavior, right?

Comment: Mhm, mocking wont be so easy either since there is no spec to mock.

Comment: Well, so funny you mention that cause the impression I've had is that mocking is real easy cause all you gotta do is just throw a duck in there! Right?!

Comment: Yea, but if you have an interface the test suite can make the duck for you, you'd just need to specify the flavour.

Comment: Ah yes. I see. It does appear that the best testing tools are in C# and Java. Makes sense. Welp, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) to enforce the types.  Essentially, what you'll do is use the objects passed in by your keys as you'd expect them to, and let the JS runtime complain if, say, `a` doesn't behave like a RegEx or you can't call `b` like a function.

Comment: Gosh that sucks. Yes, I was thinking that's the case, and now you guys are confirming this fear. So much for spec'ing via TDD. I guess I ought to just mellow out!

Comment: In short, test the golden path, and document reasonably well.  Trust the users of your object to do the right thing and help them know what that is.

Comment: **DO** still spec via TDD, just don't expect it to solve the problem of people using your objects incorrectly!

TDD is great for designing and spec'ing out the way your objects will work.  It can teach you so much about your code.  Just remember that it's _okay_ to trust your users.

Comment: I will get "Test the Golden Path" tattooed on my right forearm.